# How to access TextField label frame?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uilabel, uisearchbar, frame

I am trying to display a lock icon on the left hand side of a search bar's text field, like Safari displays when you visit a secure site, but I don't know how to set the frame.

**How can you get the frame of the label within a text field?**

Here's what I have:

```
    let lockImageView = UIImageView()
    lockImageView.image = UIImage(named: "lock")
    lockImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    lockImageView.frame = CGRect(x: searchBar.bounds.midX, y: 23, width: 11, height: 11)
    searchBar.addSubview(lockImageView)
```

Here's what it looks like because the frame for the icon is not correct: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this two to your searchBar before adding the image to the subview

```
searchBar.leftView = lockImageView
searchBar.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

Comment: This replaces the magnifying glass icon. It doesn't work. :

Comment: I guess you’ll have to add constraints to the image in this case. Let the constraint stay next to the magnifying glass icon. Hmmmm